# Solving simple harmonic oscillator equation using $x(t)=Ce^{pt}$ solution proposal

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, harmonic-oscillator

The simple harmonic oscillator equation is,

$$\frac{d^2x(t)}{dt^2}+w^2x(t)=0$$

I'm trying to solve this equation using $x(t)=Ce^{pt}$ solution proposal.

$$\frac{dx(t)}{dt}=pCe^{pt}, \frac{d^{2}x(t)}{dt^2}=p^2Ce^{pt}$$

Usuing the found expressions in simple harmonic oscillator equation, I get:

$$p^2Ce^{pt}+\omega^2Ce^{pt}=0 \Rightarrow (p^2+\omega^2)Ce^{pt}=0$$

$$p^2+\omega^2=0 \Rightarrow p^2=-\omega^2 \Rightarrow p^2=i^2\omega^2$$

$$p=i\omega$$

I found what is $p$. So the solution proposal became $x(t)=Ce^{i\omega t}$. Now, I need to find coefficient $C$. To find $C$, I need to find initial values using $t=0$ in $x(t)$ and $\frac{dx(t)}{dt}$.

$$x(0)=Ce^{i\omega(0)}=C=x_0$$

$$\frac{dx(t)}{dt}|_{t=0}=(i\omega Ce^{i\omega t})|_{t=0}=i\omega C=v_0 \Rightarrow C=\frac{v_o}{i\omega}=-i\frac{v_0}{w}$$

I ended up with 2 different values for $C$. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: @M.ÇağlarTUFAN You will obtain two solutions for your ansatz, namely $p_{\pm} = \pm i \omega$. Then you can write $x(t)$ as a linear superposition of these solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your solution proposal of $x(t) = C e^{\rho t}$, you correctly identified that you require $\rho^2 = - \omega^2$ meaning that $\rho$ could equal $i \omega$ or $- i \omega$. Also note that $C$ could be any complex number.

Therefore, the general solution identified from your proposal is actually:

$$x(t) = C_1 e^{i \omega t} + C_2 e^{-i \omega t} \tag{1}$$ where $C_1, C_2$ are complex numbers.

Therefore, as expected for a second order ordinary differential equation, you have 2 arbitrary constants ($C_1$ and $C_2$) that must be fixed by 2 initial (or boundary) conditions. When using this general solution, you will have no contradiction since you're fixing 2 constants ($C_1$ and $C_2$) by 2 conditions (instead of 1 constant by 2 conditions, which isn't possible).

Note that equation 1 can be rewritten in other forms, for example, after writing the exponentials in terms of sines and cosines, we get:

$$x(t) = (C_1 + C_2) \cos(\omega t) + i (C_1 - C_2) \sin(\omega t)$$

but the $(C_1 + C_2)$ and $i (C_1 - C_2)$ are just arbitrary constants as well so we can relabel them by, say, $A$ and $B$ respectively.

Comment: Oh, yes. Thanks for the explanation. I saw and understood where I made a mistake.

Comment: No problem! Glad you found your error.